# JUnit testing: Difference between never() and times(0)

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit, springmockito

I just want to know that what is the difference between times(0) and never() in JUnit testing.

For example I have the test line code for saving data in mongoDB:

```
verify(mockRepository,never()).save(any(User.class));
```

if I write it as:

```
verify(mockRepository,times(0)).save(any(User.class));
```

Both test shows that save method hasn't called. (correct me if I am wrong)
Is there any difference between these two ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [javadoc of the never method](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#never%28%29) says: `Alias to times(0), see Mockito.times(int)`. So `never()` is just a shortcut for `times(0)`.